# Using Field Calculator to fill out a list of unit numbers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator

I am adding address points for individual units in trailer/RV parks and I would like to be able to use the Field Calculator to assign the unit numbers.  Is it possible to tell the Field Calculator a starting number and then have it run an equation on a selection like (n)+1 where n=the previous number?  If so will it assign the numbers based on the ObjectID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From ESRI Support [HowTo: Create sequential numbers in a field using Python in the Field Calculator](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38517)